# Get verification code from a html string code using regex

Tags: regex

I am currently writing an automation script, Where I read email Gmail through API and i am getting  below html content. Now i need only code **191418** from this html content, I want to take it using regex. I tried with this

```
.*([0-9]{6})
```

To find 6 digit code but its returns 10 matchings, I am not good at regex, Can someone please help me to get the code using regex?

```
<div dir="ltr"><br><br><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr" class="gmail_attr"><br></div><u></u>
    <div>
        <center id="m_-2051398760120817894wrapper">
            <table id="m_-2051398760120817894main" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr id="m_-2051398760120817894logo">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="test.com/logo.png" width="140px" alt="xxxxx Logo" style="padding:0 10px">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="18px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894header">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="64px" style="background-color:#10069f;color:#fff;padding-left:24px;font-weight:700">Reset your password</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894content">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td style="background-color:#f6f5ff;padding:24px 24px 16px 24px">
                                    <p style="margin-top:0">The following is the verification code required to complete your password reset.</p>
                                    <p style="margin-bottom:24px">Enter the following verification code on the screen during the registration, and proceed to the next step.</p>
                                    <div style="display:block;text-align:center;margin-bottom:8px;background-color:#fff;height:92px;font-weight:600;font-size:36px;line-height:92px">191418</div>
                                    <span style="display:block;font-size:12px;color:#5d5d5d">*The verification code is valid only for 24 hours.</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="24px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894footer">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td style="background-color:#6d7777;padding:16px 24px;font-size:12px;color:#fff">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td id="m_-2051398760120817894footer-left">
                                                <span style="display:block">amnimo Inc.</span>
                                                <span style="display:block">0-3-30 usaa-fso, xxxxxxxx-shi, Tokyo, 180-8750, Japan</span>
                                                <span style="display:block">Phone: +81-422-52-6779</span>
                                                <span id="m_-2051398760120817894copyright-mb" style="margin-top:16px">© 2020 <div dir="ltr"><br><br><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr" class="gmail_attr"><br></div><u></u>
<div>
    <center id="m_-2051398760120817894wrapper">
        <table id="m_-2051398760120817894main" width="100%">
            <tbody><tr id="m_-2051398760120817894logo">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="https://test.com/logo.png" width="140px" alt="Amnimo Logo" style="padding:0 10px">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="18px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894header">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td height="64px" style="background-color:#10069f;color:#fff;padding-left:24px;font-weight:700">Reset your password</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894content">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="background-color:#f6f5ff;padding:24px 24px 16px 24px">
                                <p style="margin-top:0">The following is the verification code required to complete your password reset.</p>
                                <p style="margin-bottom:24px">Enter the following verification code on the screen during the registration, and proceed to the next step.</p>
                                <div style="display:block;text-align:center;margin-bottom:8px;background-color:#fff;height:92px;font-weight:600;font-size:36px;line-height:92px">191418</div>
                                <span style="display:block;font-size:12px;color:#5d5d5d">*The verification code is valid only for 24 hours.</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="24px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="m_-2051398760120817894footer">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="background-color:#6d7777;padding:16px 24px;font-size:12px;color:#fff">
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td id="m_-2051398760120817894footer-left">
                                            <span style="display:block">test Inc.</span>
                                            <span style="display:block">2-9-32 ssdsa-sss, puakano-shi, Tokyo, 000-8000, Japan</span>
                                            <span style="display:block">Phone: +81-000-00-652</span>
                                            <span id="m_-2051398760120817894copyright-mb" style="margin-top:16px">© 2020 amnimo Inc.</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="m_-2051398760120817894footer-right">
                                            <span style="display:block">© 2020 amnimo Inc.</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </center>
</div>
</div></div> Inc.</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td id="m_-2051398760120817894footer-right">
                                                <span style="display:block">© 2020 test Inc.</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </center>
    </div>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use some DOM library that will let you query the element you want and get its content. [Parsing HTML with regex is bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

If you must do it, getting six numbers is not enough - after inspecting, I see that it's `div` content. So I would write something among the lines:

```
<div[^>]*>\d{6}<\/div>
```

Pattern explanation:

`<div` - match `<div` literally

`[^>]*` - match zero or more characters other from `>`

`>` - match `>` literally

`\d{6}` - match 6 digits

`<\/div>` - match `<\/div>` literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B9sCrH/1)

**EDIT**

In order to extract desired text, use capturing groups:

```
<div[^>]*>(\d{6})<\/div>
```

Then text in first capturing group will be your desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but its return full div <div style="display:block;text-align:center;margin-bottom:8px;background-color:#fff;height:92px;font-weight:600;font-size:36px;line-height:92px">191418</div>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try word boundaries, which will prevent matching inside longer numbers:

`\b([0-9]{6})\b`

https://regex101.com/r/dQAiHU/1/